# Will Tom have to go to hostel or Will Tom has to go to hostel?

Tags: sentence-construction

I thought Tom is singular thus I should use has rather than have.
Here are two sentences.

1. Will Tom have to go to a hostel?
2. Will Tom has to go to a hostel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [He will has written the essay or He will have written the essay (Future Perfect Tense)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119669/he-will-has-written-the-essay-or-he-will-have-written-the-essay-future-perfect)

Comment: There is a difference here - in my question I have a subject name rather than a pronoun. Does it work the same way? Which one is correct? Will Tom have to go to a hostel? or Will Tom has to go to a hostel?

Comment: Modals such as _will_, _would_, _can_, _could_, _shall_, _should_, _may_, _must_, _might_ **always always always** take the base form of their verb they govern, never an inflected form. This applies even when the verb they govern is itself an auxiliary such as _have_ or _be_.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Try converting to statements:

> (1) Tom will have to go to a hostel.

> (2) Tom will has to go to a hostel.

Only statement (1) is correct.  The correct grammar is to follow the modal verb "will" by a bare infinitive "have".

When you form a question you invert the modal auxiliary and the subject, but the word "have" remains unchanged.

> Will Tom have....